# Matplotlib changes values of input vector and outputs wrong plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, debugging, jupyter-lab

I'm using Python version 3.9.7 and Matplotlib 3.4.2 and when I run the following commands in Jupyter Lab, I get the output shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0.65945484, 0.65945478])
```

[image: Matplotlib changes the input values and adds a weird text to the top of the output]

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be better explained using different values.

**1.** If you run `plt.plot([12, 5])`, you may see that you get a similar descending line. Taking a look at the y-axis we can see that it spans from `5` to `12`, i.e. our input values, whereas the x-axis spans from `0` to `1`.

**2.** If you then run `plt.plot([0,1], [12, 5])` we can see the exact same line with the exact same axes values.

[image]

**So what's happening?**

Looking at **2.** our inputs lists are taken as coordinates. In particular, it is as if we were providing two points, say `A = (0, 12)` and `B = (1, 5)`, and `plt.plot()` is drawing a line from point `A` to point `B`. In other words, we are doing

```
x0 = 0
x1 = 1

y0 = 12
y1 = 5

plt.plot([x0, x1], [y0, y1])
```

The same happens with your case, where you provide only one list. Here, the single list is interpreted as `[y0, y1]`, and the missing `[x0, x1]`, since it is not provided, is set as its default `[0, 1]`.

In conclusion, your code is drawing a line from the point `(0, 0.65945484)` to the point `(1, 0.65945478)`. And yes, the axes values suck.

Answer (score 0):

`plt.plot` is changing the scale of the y-axis to the point that the labels become hard to understand. The text at the top is the scale. 1e-8 is multiplied by the y-tick labels and added to 6.5945400000e-1 and that gives the input values.